# Implementing a Difference of Sets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

### Background:

I was refactoring code from a personal project and want to know which of the middle two code chunks in the examples is best to use when creating a set from another set in the given type of scenario. The specific conditions and elements inserted are irrelevant.

**Basic Example**

```
import itertools

# Example set
mySet={(6,6), (6,7), (6,8), (7,6), (7,7), (7,8)}
```

```
# First implementation
symmetric=set()
for x in mySet:
    # Compare all for every element
    if (x[1],x[0]) not in mySet:
        # Append some reversed
        symmetric.add(x[::-1])
hold=symmetric
```

```
# Second implementation
symmetric=set()
for x in mySet:
    # Append all reversed
    symmetric.add(x[::-1])
# Compare all via the implied algorithm
symmetric-=mySet
```

```
# Illustrate that the sets are identical
print('The sets are identical.') if (hold==symmetric) else print('The sets are not identical.')
```

**More Complicated Example**

```
import itertools

# Example set
mySet={(6,6), (6,7), (6,8), (7,6), (7,7), (7,8)}
```

```
# First implementation
someSet=set()
# Demonstrates use of itertools in for loop
for (a,b) in itertools.combinations(mySet, 2):
    # Demonstrates initialization and/or assignment
    pair=(a[0],b[1])
    # Demonstrates possibility of multiple conditions
    if a[0]==b[0] and pair not in mySet:
        someSet.add(pair)
hold=someSet
```

```
# Second implementation
someSet=set()
for (a,b) in itertools.combinations(mySet, 2):
    pair=(a[0],b[1])
    if a[0]==b[0]:
        someSet.add(pair)
someSet-=mySet
```

```
# Illustrate that the sets are identical
print('The sets are identical.') if (hold==someSet) else print('The sets are not identical.')
```

---

### Questions:

- How exactly do the implementations differ in this context?
- Which should be used for this scenario when there are *many* and/or *large* quantities in the set(s)?

For instance:

```
# First implementation
newSet=set()
for x in mySet:
    if pair not in setA and pair not in setB: # Given some setA and setB
        newSet.add(x[::-1])
hold=newSet
```

```
# Second implementation
newSet=set()
for x in mySet:
    newSet.add(x[::-1])
newSet=newSet-setA-setB # s1.difference(s2, s3)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with your code? Can you describe this in one or two sentences? I.e. what are the inputs and what are the outputs?

Comment: @a_guest mySet is the input and hold/symmetric are identical outputs. mySet is the input and hold/someSet are identical outputs for the second example. I am only concerned with which section of code is preferred for either example.

Comment: By looking at your code, I don't understand what it's supposed to do, so it's hard to judge what would be the best approach. Hence I'd asked if you could explain the purpose of the code in a few sentences. That would greatly help in understanding what's going on.

Comment: By the way, in the first code block at the end of your question, I suppose you want to use `and` instead of `or` because otherwise it's not the same as the second code block. And why are you using lists to construct your sets? Why not use `newSet = set()` and then `newSet.add(...)`? If you can spare redundant operations such as adding an element and then removing later on, that's definitely a good idea, so the first block should be more efficient.

Comment: The first example shows that a set is mathematically symmetric (contains the inverses of all of its elements). However, the "purpose" is not important. This means the specific condition and what elements are appended is irrelevant while the rest is necessary to the question.

Comment: Well then I can only repeat what I wrote in my comment above: doing unnecessary work and then undoing that work is always going to be slower, so the first approach is what you should do (correcting for `and` vs. `or`).

Comment: Yes, that has been fixed. It was originally like that to allow for input to be in other data structures. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: If both codes work then use the timeit module and find the most efficient one yourself.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Will do, however, I wanted reasoning.

Comment: Sometimes reasoning is non-obvious.  If it matters, measure.